# C# Subscribe a Method to a System.Action, but with predefined arguments

Tags: c#

I have a class that is listening to a lot of action's, and then when these are invoked do a similar thing but to different objects depending on which action was invoked. My thoughts are:

If I have

```
System.Action<SomeType> SomeAction;
void SomeMethod(SomeType type);
```

I can do

```
SomeAction += SomeMethod;
```

My question is then, if I have another class say

```
void SomeOtherMethod(SomeType type, SomePredefinedType)
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
SomePredefinedType SomeValue;
SomeAction += SomeMethod(SomeValue);
```

that is, to Subscribe a method with two arguments to a action with one argument by predefining the exces argument?

Comment: Why do you call methods as classes?

Comment: Indeed - it would be really helpful to follow normal .NET naming conventions, and name things after what they actually are. (A [mcve] rather than snippets would also help.)

Comment: That said, the way to do that is simply to use a closure to write an adapter `SomePredefinedType SomeValue;
SomeAction += st => SomeOtherClass(st, SomeValue);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it with a method group conversion like this, but you can easily do it with a lambda expression:

```cs
SomePredefinedType extraArgument = ...;
SomeAction += value => SomeOtherMethod(value, extraArgument);
```

Comment: This is the approach I was looking for Thank you! Something to keep in mind is that 'extraArgument' is a reference, so if you change that reference later down the line it will change in the subscription too.

Comment: @MikaelWendt: It's not that it's a reference - it's a variable. And yes, that variable's current value is used everywhere. (The term reference has a very specific meaning in C#, and it's not the right one here.)